# is there a vnc client for the mac that I can use to vnc-into my windows server?

Tags: windows-xp, macbook, vnc

I use a MacBook during the day and I have two Windows servers that are remote that I want to access using my MacBook.  I have VNC installed on the Windows CPUs, now I want to test controlling from my remote macbook.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the built in VNC client in Mac OS X? It's called "Screen Sharing".

Comment: Don't know .. noob here.   How do I invoke it?  find it?

Comment: isn't that for others to view my screen??  I want to use my Mac to remote access my Windowz boxes.

Comment: Run the screen sharing app, don't configure sharing settings. You'll get a dialog that looks like http://igadgetlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/ScreenSharingApp.jpg

Comment: OK .. so from Finder -> %K (pop-up for servers) enter vnc://myserver and as long as myserver is network accessible and is running vnc server, I should be good to go ?!  Correct??

Answer (score 0):

[Try the Remote Desktop Connection for MAC.](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client)